# SWRL rules comparing individuals from two (2) classes

Tags: python, ontology, swrl, owlready

I have a simple ontology with different classes, which `courses` and `lessons` are classes. I'm trying to run a SWRL rule that associates a property `belongsTo` to individuals of the `lessons`. I'm using [OWLReady2](https://readthedocs.org/projects/owlready2/downloads/pdf/latest/) and Python

```
with onto:
    #courses
    class course_id (onto.courses >> int): pass
    class course_title (onto.courses >> str): pass
    #lessons
    class lesson_id (onto.lessons >> int): pass
    class lesson_title (onto.lessons >> str): pass
    class course_id (onto.lessons >> int): pass
    

    class belongTo(onto.lessons >> onto.courses): pass

    rule = Imp()
    rule.set_as_rule("""lessons(?l), courses(?c), course_id(?c, ?cid), course_id(?l, ?cid) -> belongTo(?l, ?c) """)



sync_reasoner_pellet(infer_property_values = True, infer_data_property_values = True)
```

The idea is that if the `course_id` are similar, the lesson should belong to the course. But my code does not seem to be working. I'm getting these inferences:

```
* Owlready * Adding relation lmsontology.Introduction belongTo lmsontology.Introduction
* Owlready * Adding relation lmsontology.Databases belongTo lmsontology.Databases
```

Comment: what means "not working"? what do you do after you added the rule? Is there any data matching the rule body?

Comment: @UninformedUser I've added more details to the code and the error message. By data matching the rule and body, do you mean instances of both classes?

Comment: @UninformedUser I resolved the error, but the inferences are not what I'm expecting

Comment: I don't see why the rule should not work with Pellet. As I asked before, your instance data does match the body of the rule? Such that it will be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

In your example I detect the following issues:

- The classes for `courses` and `lessons` are missing.
- `course_id` is defined twice making the first one obsolete
- The example does not stick to the usual naming convention: singular nouns for concepts and verb-expressions like `hasId` for roles.
- No individuals are defined, so afaik the swrl rules have essentially nothing to apply to, when you run the reasoner.

In general to debug rules I would suggest to incrementally build it up from a trivial rule or working example and in each step checking whether the result is as expected.